# How to support white label solutions in a single codebase using Next.js and Tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I'm trying to figure out the best way to support white label brands within a single codebase using Next.js and Tailwind CSS. What I've come up with so far is to have a predefined custom plugin for each brand, and conditionally swap this plugin based on `process.env.BRAND` env variable when building each instance of the app. Everything works great so far, brand themes are isolated and the correct fonts are included in each build, however the conditional logic of swapping plugins based on env variables seems to break the Tailwind Intellisense plugin.

**I'm just wondering if anyone has tried to achieve something similar, or would advise against my current solution? Any potential problems this might cause with Next.js or Tailwind CSS?**

I'm aware Tailwind CSS has a `@config` directory, however this only seems to be useful for projects that need more than one `tailwind.config.ts` file within the same build. ie. One config for admin routes, and another for public routes. I need entirely isolated builds, one for each brand (each with their respective theme/plugin).

**The current solution:**

**global.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;`
```

**tailwind.config.ts**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

import plugin from 'tailwindcss/plugin';

const animatePlugin = require('tailwindcss-animate');

const brandOnePlugin = plugin(
  function ({ addBase, theme }) {
    addBase({
      '@font-face': {
        'font-family': 'NunitoSans',
        'font-display': 'fallback',
        'font-weight': '400',
        src: "url('/NunitoSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype')",
      },
    });
    addBase({
      '@font-face': {
        'font-family': 'NunitoSans',
        'font-display': 'fallback',
        'font-weight': '700',
        src: "url('/NunitoSans-Bold.ttf') format('truetype')",
      },
    });
    addBase({
      html: {
        'font-family': theme('fontFamily.primary'),
      },
      ':root': {
        '--background': '0 0% 100%',
        '--foreground': '240 10% 3.9%',
        '--card': '0 0% 100%',
        '--card-foreground': '240 10% 3.9%',
        '--popover': '0 0% 100%',
        '--popover-foreground': '240 10% 3.9%',
        '--primary': '346.8 77.2% 49.8%',
        '--primary-foreground': '355.7 100% 97.3%',
        '--secondary': '240 4.8% 95.9%',
        '--secondary-foreground': '240 5.9% 10%',
        '--muted': '240 4.8% 95.9%',
        '--muted-foreground': '240 3.8% 46.1%',
        '--accent': '240 4.8% 95.9%',
        '--accent-foreground': '240 5.9% 10%',
        '--destructive': '0 84.2% 60.2%',
        '--destructive-foreground': '0 0% 98%',
        '--border': '240 5.9% 90%',
        '--input': '240 5.9% 90%',
        '--ring': '346.8 77.2% 49.8%',
      },
    });
  },
  {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        fontFamily: {
          primary: ['NunitoSans', 'sans-serif'],
          secondary: ['NunitoSans', 'sans-serif'],
        },
      },
    },
  },
);

const brandTwoPlugin = plugin(
  function ({ addBase, theme }) {
    addBase({
      '@font-face': {
        'font-family': 'Montserrat',
        'font-display': 'fallback',
        'font-weight': '400',
        src: "url('/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('truetype')",
      },
    });
    addBase({
      '@font-face': {
        'font-family': 'Montserrat',
        'font-display': 'fallback',
        'font-weight': '700',
        src: "url('/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') format('truetype')",
      },
    });
    addBase({
      html: {
        'font-family': theme('fontFamily.primary'),
      },
      ':root': {
        '--background': '0 0% 100%',
        '--foreground': '20 14.3% 4.1%',
        '--card': '0 0% 100%',
        '--card-foreground': '20 14.3% 4.1%',
        '--popover': '0 0% 100%',
        '--popover-foreground': '20 14.3% 4.1%',
        '--primary': '24.6 95% 53.1%',
        '--primary-foreground': '60 9.1% 97.8%',
        '--secondary': '60 4.8% 95.9%',
        '--secondary-foreground': '24 9.8% 10%',
        '--muted': '60 4.8% 95.9%',
        '--muted-foreground': '25 5.3% 44.7%',
        '--accent': '60 4.8% 95.9%',
        '--accent-foreground': '24 9.8% 10%',
        '--destructive': '0 84.2% 60.2%',
        '--destructive-foreground': '60 9.1% 97.8%',
        '--border': '20 5.9% 90%',
        '--input': '20 5.9% 90%',
        '--ring': '24.6 95% 53.1%',
        '--radius': '0.75rem',
      },
    });
  },
  {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        fontFamily: {
          primary: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],
          secondary: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],
        },
      },
    },
  },
);

const brand = process.env.BRAND // 'brandOne' | 'brandTwo'

const theme = {
  brandOne: brandOnePlugin,
  brandTwo: brandTwoPlugin,
} as const;

const brandPlugin = theme[brand as keyof typeof theme];

const plugins = [animatePlugin, brandPlugin];

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: '2rem',
      screens: {
        '2xl': '1400px',
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: 'hsl(var(--border))',
        input: 'hsl(var(--input))',
        ring: 'hsl(var(--ring))',
        background: 'hsl(var(--background))',
        foreground: 'hsl(var(--foreground))',
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--primary))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--primary-foreground))',
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--secondary))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))',
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--destructive))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))',
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--muted))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--muted-foreground))',
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--accent))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--accent-foreground))',
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--popover))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--popover-foreground))',
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--card))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--card-foreground))',
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: 'var(--radius)',
        md: 'calc(var(--radius) - 2px)',
        sm: 'calc(var(--radius) - 4px)',
      },
      keyframes: {
        'accordion-down': {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: 'var(--radix-accordion-content-height)' },
        },
        'accordion-up': {
          from: { height: 'var(--radix-accordion-content-height)' },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        'accordion-down': 'accordion-down 0.2s ease-out',
        'accordion-up': 'accordion-up 0.2s ease-out',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins,
};
```

I've also tried to conditionally import global.css files (ie brandOne.css or brandTwo.css), but Next.js doesn't have support for this.